# Show and hide panel (Powershell GUI)

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface

When hover over the word "test", a panel appears. While the cursor on the panel (yellow area) the panel is visible. All is well. However, when I hover over the elements of panel ("Word" and button), the panel is hidden. However, I do not want this. I want the panel to hide when I move the cursor out of the panel area. Question: How can I do this? Many thanks

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms

$Main = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Main.Width = 300
$Main.Height = 200
$Main.BackColor = '255, 255, 255'
$Main.StartPosition = 'CenterParent'

$Test = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Test.Left = 10
$Test.Top = 10
$Test.Text = 'Test'

$Test.Add_MouseHover({ $Panel.Show() })

$Panel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$Panel.Left = 0
$Panel.Top = 10
$Panel.Width = 200
$Panel.Height = 100
$Panel.BackColor = '255, 255, 0'
$Panel.Hide()

$Panel.Add_MouseLeave({ $Panel.Hide() })

$Word = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Word.Left = 80
$Word.Top = 20
$Word.Text = 'Word'

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Left = 50
$Button.Top = 50
$Button.Width = 100
$Button.Height = 30

$Main.Controls.Add($Panel)
$Main.Controls.Add($Test)
$Panel.Controls.Add($Word)
$Panel.Controls.Add($Button)

$Main.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Just because you *can* build a GUI in powershell does not mean you *should*. I strongly discourage it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event fires when the panel is left which also occurs when you're hovering over your label / button.

Anyway this is how I got it working:

```
$Panel.Add_MouseLeave({
    $point = [System.drawing.Point]::new([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X + 1,[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y + 1)
    if ($panel.width -lt $panel.PointToClient($point).X -or
        $panel.height -lt $panel.PointToClient($point).Y){
        $Panel.Hide()
    }
 })
```

Notice the manipulation of the cursor position (+1), else it is still within your panel.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your elements in the panel are outside of the panel.
So entering either of those two is firing the ...

```
$Panel.Add_MouseLeave({ $Panel.Hide() })
```

... code. You can validate this by commenting out that line and watch the behavior.

You also have another issue, in that the word 'Test' hides on your hover event in the panel as well, and that does not sound like something you'd want either.

This is not a PowerShell specific question or problem. This is a GUI design issue, as this would occur in your GUI design whether you were using PowerShell or other programming language using this WinForms/WPF design.

A quick and dirty fix would be to do this on the form instead. For example:

```
# $Panel.Add_MouseLeave({ $Panel.Hide() })
$Main.Add_MouseEnter({ $Panel.Hide() })
```

Now, the above is not the only answer to this, but, you should really head over to Youtube, and view some of the Winforms/WPF GUI design videos to get better edification on that topic. You can then weave in needed PowerShell stuff later.